# How can I change a picture's file size?

Tags: files, image-processing

Every so often, I try to upload a picture to a website and encounter a message:

> Upload failed: the file size can't exceed *n* MB!

I know that resizing the picture's dimension should get me below *n* at a certain point, but the process of resizing, saving, checking file size is cumbersome. Furthermore, at times it may be handy to keep the current dimensions.

I'm looking for a way to change a picture's file size, preferably from the terminal. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could try `jpegoptim` which is a commandline too to optimize jpegs. In general i would think about either resizing or compressing or a combination of both if your target is reducing filesize

Comment: You could use another type of compression, .jpg instead of .png. ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org) has both commandline an basic graphical interface

Comment: ImageMagick has a switch that allows to set the file size (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write), unfortunately only for `jpg` (similar to `jpegoptim`). Quote: 'It works by generating many versions of the JPEG image, doing a binary search, of the output quality "-quality" setting, until it gets as close as possible to the file size given without exceeding it' (end quote). Maybe you can write a script that mimicks this behaviour for other formats.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## jpegoptim

First install `jpegoptim` via

```
sudo apt install jpegoptim
```

Then either try to optimize filesize of your image via

```
jpegoptim /path/to/image.jpg
```

or if you need a defined size via

```
jpegoptim --size=512k /path/to/image.jpg
```

This will overwrite the image - to make sure you have a backup while testing with `jpegoptim`.

## mogrify (imagemagick)

### Resizing

You could as well use `mogrify` which is part of `imagemagick`. The following example shrinks the image dimensions to 50% (so resizing - not compressing)

```
mogrify -resize 50% /path/to/image.jpg
```

### Compressing

The following example shows compressing with `mogrify`:

```
mogrify -compress JPEG -quality 50 /path/to/image.jpg
```

## convert (imagemagick)

### Compressing

Compressing to 80% using convert works as follows:

```
convert -quality 80% /path/to/source/image.jpg /path/to/result/image.jpg
```

Convert somes with a huge set of options, so you could use

```
convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 85% /path/to/source/image.jpg /path/to/result/image.jpg
```

which should according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261855/recommendation-for-compressing-jpg-files-with-imagemagick):

- set the quality to 85
- progressive (comprobed compression)
- a very tiny gausssian blur to optimize the size (0.05 or 0.5 of radius) depends on the quality and size of the picture, this notably optimizes the size of the jpeg.
- Strip any comment or exif tag

## trimage

I am quoting the [project page](https://trimage.org/) here

> Trimage is a cross-platform GUI and command-line interface to optimize
>   image files for websites, using optipng, pngcrush, advpng and
>   jpegoptim, depending on the filetype (currently, PNG and JPG files are
>   supported).

You can simply install it via

```
sudo apt install trimage
```

After starting via just the application name you might see the UI

[image]

If you need more information about trimage either visit the project page or run `trimage -h` to take a look on the help.

## Other tools

There is as well `optipng`, `pngcrush`, `jpegtran` and several other tools in the image-size-optimization-corner .... but i've never used them.

I'll end with some links

- [OptiPNG - http://optipng.sourceforge.net/](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)
- [Trimage - https://trimage.org/](https://trimage.org/)
- [PNGCrush - http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)