# PNG Image Compression for Wordpress

Tags: compression

Wordpress site getting heavier due to images , checked through google insights which states to compress images as its slowing down the site.
There are many online venues but I need a opensource .deb software that I can install on ubuntu 16.04 for bulk and future use.
Note I already have smush plugin installed but being free its hasnt done what it takes. No complaints there since its free.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **mogrify** and **convert** utilities from ImageMagick package. It is pretty useful for bulk scenarios like this. 
 
**A small working mogrify example would be:-**

```
mogrify -compress JPEG -quality 5 /path/to/image.jpg
```

P.S: This will overwrite the source file so make sure you have a backup.

**A small working convert example would be:-**

```
convert -quality 80% /path/to/source/image.jpg /path/to/result/image.jpg
```

The above command as is evident reduces the quality to 80% of the original image.
A small bash script can call this command repeatedly for bulk use.
For futher details refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/818599/502522)